# How can I upload Photostream pictures to Flickr

Tags: photo-stream, flickr

I want to (automatically if possible) upload the content of my Photostream to Flickr. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a plugin to upload photos of your choosing to Flickr (albeit not automatically).

- [FlickrExport](http://connectedflow.com/flickrexport/iphoto/)
- [FFXporter](http://dustin.li/code/ffxporter/)